# How to mount encrypted volume at login (Ubuntu 12.04, pam_mount)

Tags: permissions, mount, encryption, hard-drive

I'm trying to get pam_mount working on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have /dev/sda1 (encrypted partition) with /dev/dm-1 (ext4 formatted) inside it.

Should ~/.pam_mount.conf.xml be trying to mount /dev/sda1 or /dev/dm-1?

If I use the line:

```
<volume fstype="ext4" path="/dev/dm-1" mountpoint="~/slowstore" options="rw" />
```

then it nearly works. It prompts for the password (ok, I'd like pam_mount to do that for me, but still..) then I get:

```
pam_mount(rdconf2.c:126): checking sanity of luserconf volume record (/dev/dm-1)
pam_mount(rdconf2.c:132): user-defined volume (/dev/dm-1), volume not owned by user
```

If I do:

```
sudo chown nick:disk /dev/dm-1
```

Then re-login the encrypted partition mounts correctly (ignoring th fact I have to reneter the password). However, if I log out completely the ownership on /dev/dm-1 gets reset to root:disk.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you played with `noroot="1"` option which `man pam_mount.conf` mentions?

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130199

Comment: @MountainX that uses truecrypt, which isn't what I was trying to do at all. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure udev to automatically set permissions. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23955/permanently-changing-the-ownership-or-group-of-lvm-volume (reported here)

- run `udevadm info --query=all --name /dev/dm-1` to get volume group name (`E: DM_VG_NAME=...` line) and logical volume name (`E: DM_LV_NAME=...` line) of the partition (you may know them already though through other ways)
- create a file (or modify one that looks like should hold custom rules/disk rules) in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` adding the line

  ENV{DM_VG_NAME}=="..." ENV{DM_LV_NAME}=="..." OWNER="nick"

Of course, replace `...` with relevant information.

Reload udev rules by rebooting if possible (so that you can test if it works at boot), or by running

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

notes: if you create a new file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` it should be named `DD-whatever.conf`, where `DD` are two decimal digits. The rules are parsed in number order, so your rule should have an higher number than the system rule setting the default ownership values in order to override it. If it doesn't work, change the number to `95` or so

Comment: This looks right to me.

Comment: I also noticed that when I upgraded to 14.04 it seems to magically have started working. I haven't looked into what changed.

Comment: @NickLothian I guess the default rule for devices in `udev` has changed so that your user is in the group assigned to them

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really answering your question, so I wish I could leave it as a comment, but I think this link can help you out some. https://askubuntu.com/questions/73435/pam-mount-wont-automount-encrypted-partiton In the example they had, they pointed at the partition, set fstype to crypt, and defined a user in the line. Here's an example taken directly from the link, so believe me, I don't want to take credit for the answer. I hope that link helps!

`<volume user="user" fstype="crypt" path="/dev/sda5" mountpoint="/media/personal" options="fsck,relatime" />`

Comment: That looks pretty similar to what I have. I don't see anything that would fix the "volume not owned by user" problem (or am I missing something?)